# .htaccess not redirecting all pages to non www version

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The site in question is https://thefriendlygearpage.com

If you visit that, you'll see it works fine.

Now go to https://www.thefriendlygearpage.com

It doesn't work, and if you look at the URL bar, it drops the .com from the end.

Not go to https://www.thefriendlygearpage.com/forums/forum-issues-reporting.230/

That page works just fine and redirects you to the non www version of the page, as it should.

Near as I can tell, every page in the site works just fine except for the home page. If you go to the www version of the site, it should redirect you to the non www version, plain and simple.

Here's my .htaccess file just incase it helps. I'm stumped here!

```
#   Mod_security can interfere with uploading of content such as attachments. If you
#   cannot attach files, remove the "#" from the lines below.
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#   SecFilterEngine Off
#   SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>

 ErrorDocument 401 default
 ErrorDocument 403 default
 ErrorDocument 404 default
 ErrorDocument 405 default
 ErrorDocument 406 default
 ErrorDocument 500 default
 ErrorDocument 501 default
 ErrorDocument 503 default

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thefriendlygearpage\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thefriendlygearpage.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On

#    If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
#    line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
#    of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
#RewriteBase /xenforo

#    This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow... stupid me. It was nothing more than a cached browser error. I cleared my browser cache and it works fine now.